# Reactjs resize images while keeping the correct aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm working on a PWA with create-react-app. I'm trying to create a function to upload images, and display them within a div with certain bounds. I have searched this platform for possible answers but keep finding react-native related solutions.

When I'm trying to fit an image in a parent div the image either gets streched to fit to the div's proportions, or it completely ignores the bounds of the div and increases it's size.

let say i have the following div and image:

```
    <div
      style={{
        height: "60vh",
        width:  "100%",
      }}
    >
      <img src={item.image}/>
    </div>
```

**How can i resize the image to fit within the bounds of the parent div, while maintaining the correct aspect ratio for that image so it doesnt look stretched on android and iOS devices?** Because there are many different phones and cameras, images can have different aspect ratios.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Set only width or height (not both) and use [aspect-ratio css](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio)

Comment: Looks like this doesn't support all browsers, i will edit my question to clarify

Comment: Then you can specify "default" width and height on `img` tag like `<img src="" width="100" height="50" />` and then in css change only height or only width. This should preserve aspect ratio and be supported by all browsers

Comment: set image `max-width:100%` and `max-height:100%`. your div/image container should have specific `height` and `width` defined.

Comment: @ciekals11 this seems to point me in the right direction. can i also base the width and height on percentages instead of pixels?

Comment: [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) says: `width: The intrinsic width of the image in pixels. Must be an integer without a unit.`

Comment: You can use [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) property as well. For example: You have width and height on image. Then in css add `.this-img-class {width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: contain;}`